# Spring @scheduled cron expression over night

Tags: spring-scheduled

Just wondering is this a correct @Scheduled cron expression if you want it to run every third minute between 21pm until 6am:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 */3 21-6 * * ?")
```

will it run over the night?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it should be `21-23,0-6`

Comment: I am running a test now tomorrow morning I will know for sure!

Answer (score 1):

I guess it should be `@Scheduled(cron="0 */3 21-23,0-6 * * ?")`. Please have a look at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQiCjQkM06U&t=94s) to know different possible ways to use cron expression.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the cron to stop at 6:00, you have to write 5 instead of 6 in your range as the entire hour will be included otherwise, so:

`@Scheduled(cron="0 */3 21-23,0-5 * * *")`

I find [this website](https://bradymholt.github.io/cron-expression-descriptor/) very helpful to help you write cron expressions that are valid for Spring format.

It gives this explanation: **Every 3 minutes, at 09:00 PM through 11:59 PM and 12:00 AM through 05:59 AM**